# Get the results of an (existing) code inspection

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, intellij-plugin

I am new to writing intellij plugins, so I apologize in advance if my question might be a bit unclear.

**I know** that (live) code inspections are achieved via [Annotators](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/annotator.html) or [LocalInspectionTools](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/custom_language_support/code_inspections_and_intentions.html). I also know there is an API to write a custom Annotator or Inspection tool and I have seen several examples.

**What I do not know (my question)**: is there a manager/helper/"global inspector" that can provide me with the results of an existing code annotator/inspection process (done by the IDE's plugins or by some 3rd party plugin)?

**For instance**: I do not want to write a custom Lint annotator/inspection plugin for WebStorm. One can configure JSLint/JSHint inside WebStorm settings. The results of the live inspection can be seen over the current file/current open editor. 
I would like to get the results of this live inspection, that occurs in the current open editor (inside my own custom code). For this I am interested in the API to get this annotator/inspector and/or the results it provides.

(I apologize for maybe using annotator and inspection terms in a confusing manner)

If there is another question (which I could not find) that duplicates what I have asked above, please re-direct me.

Thank you in advance!
Andrei.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately regular annotating process for the linters is asynchronous so you cannot get the annotation results directly (by calling 'Manager' method).

You can create instances of JSLintInspection, JSHintInspection, etc. and call #`createVisitor().visit(File)` method but the operation is very slow and you must call it outside of AWT thread.

Also you can try to run the method `com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DaemonCodeAnalyzerEx#processHighlights` but as I mentioned above the annotation results for linters can be not available (or outdated)

Comment: Thank you for the help; I tried what you suggested and some other things.  More here (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000015024/comments/115000040990). But trying to get the annotation results is harder than I expected. No success yet, but I am still trying. Thanks!

Comment: Seems I got to add a custom annotator, that overrides another external annotator (the one whose results I am interested in) and get hold of some results. It's not fast (as it duplicates annotator runs), but I get the results; I will post a longer answer. But I will still look for better solutions